# Run python tests from different files in parrallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytest

I am working on integration tests, written in python and run with pytest.
They are defined/written in different python files, but all these tests are executed sequentially.
Part of the tests include testing of starting and stopping of machines, and this takes a while.
That is why i want to run the start/stopping tests and the other tests in parallel.
I found libraries like "pytest-parallel" and "pytest-xdist", but they provide means to run several tests simultaneously, which does not work for me, because in this case the tests for starting and stopping a machine are run simultaneously and the tests fail.
So is there a way to make the tests from different files to run simultaneously, but the tests from within a file to be run sequentially?

Comment: If you need strict ordering for some tests, check out pytest-order: https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/stable/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's built-in to `pytest-xdist`: [`--dist=loadfile`](https://pytest-xdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distribution.html#distribution-modes).

> Tests are grouped by their containing file. Groups are distributed to available workers as whole units. This guarantees that all tests in a file run in the same worker.

However,

> the tests for starting and stopping a machine are run simultaneously and the tests fail

sounds like you'd want the machine to start and stop in a [`@pytest.fixture(scope="module")`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session) or similar...

Comment: If it involves starting something that takes time and after starting will be used throughout the test, might even use `scope="session"`

Comment: I used         --dist=loadfile \
        -n 3 \
        --tx 3*popen \   . ,but i feel, the tests in a file are not executed sequentially....is that possible as with "--dist=loadfile." we specify, that the tests in a file are executed by only one thread?!?!?!?...My suspicions come from the fact, that i have start/stop operations, executed sequentially. When i execute the tests without "--dist=loadfile." and the other flags for parallelization, everything runs smoothy, but no when the parallelization flags are raised.